# How do I copy over data from one table to another which has new columns?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have `Table A` and `Table B`.

Both used to have same content but now table A has a few extra non nullable columns. I am trying to copy over data from Table B into Table A but getting an error when I try this query,

```
INSERT INTO TABLE_A (SELECT * FROM TABLE_B);
```

This throws the error, `ORA-00947: not enough values`

```
INSERT INTO TABLE_A(Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4)
VALUES ((SELECT Col1 FROM TABLE_B), (SELECT Col3 FROM TABLE_B), 'New Column', 'New Column');
```

This throws the error, `ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row`

Comment: Never rely on any column order in the table, because any permutation of columns will provide the same interface for the cumsumer. Always specify exavt columns in the `select` list and corresponding `insert`. This will allow any strycture change in both source and target.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE_A (Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4)
(SELECT Col1, Col3, 'New Column', 'New Column' FROM TABLE_B);
```

This should return all the rows from `TABLE_B` with the correct number of columns.

Comment: but `TABLE_B` does not have new columns. Only `TABLE_A` has it.

Comment: And we're supposed to know TABLE_A and TABLE_B descriptions exactly how (unless you share that info with us)?

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned in question itself table structure of A and B are different.
This is the reason why `INSERT INTO SELECT..` is failing.

Below is the query for reference:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE_A (Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4)
(
SELECT Col1, Col3, 'DUMMY', 'DUMMY' 
FROM TABLE_B
);
```